# encryption sqliteDB using attached DB not encrypting anything?

Tags: ios, sqlite

i've followed the [sqlcipher tutorial](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/)

all linking done well  compiled, and build very well...

now the turn came to encrypt the data wich should be the easiest part ,, I've used the attached database approch explained in [How to encrypt a plaintext SQLite database to use SQLCipher](http://zetetic.net/blog/2009/12/29/how-to-encrypt-a-plaintext-sqlite-database-to-use-sqlcipher/)

actually I dont' get it very well,,
when we use

> sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA key = 'BIGsecret', NULL, NULL, NULL);

we encrypt or decrypt or both !!!!

Any ideas ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so since the problem solved for me ..
I had to go under the sqlcipher directory where i can use ./config
then i linked to the libcrypto.a dynamically as in the tutorial
and i had to use ./sqlite3 not sqlite because the version is differ .
and then every thing went ok :)